# Concat byte arrays

Tags: go

Can someone please point at a more efficient version of the following

```
    b:=make([]byte,0,sizeTotal)
    b=append(b,size...)
    b=append(b,contentType...)
    b=append(b,lenCallbackid...)
    b=append(b,lenTarget...)
    b=append(b,lenAction...)
    b=append(b,lenContent...)
    b=append(b,callbackid...)
    b=append(b,target...)
    b=append(b,action...)
    b=append(b,content...)
```

every variable is a byte slice apart from size `sizeTotal`

`Update`:

Code:

```
type Message struct {
    size        uint32
    contentType uint8
    callbackId  string
    target      string
    action      string
    content     string
}


var res []byte
var b []byte = make([]byte,0,4096)

func (m *Message)ToByte()[]byte{
    callbackIdIntLen:=len(m.callbackId)
    targetIntLen := len(m.target)
    actionIntLen := len(m.action)
    contentIntLen := len(m.content)
    lenCallbackid:=make([]byte,4)
    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(lenCallbackid, uint32(callbackIdIntLen))
    callbackid := []byte(m.callbackId)
    lenTarget := make([]byte,4)
    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(lenTarget, uint32(targetIntLen))
    target:=[]byte(m.target)
    lenAction := make([]byte,4)
    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(lenAction, uint32(actionIntLen))
    action := []byte(m.action)
    lenContent:= make([]byte,4)
    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(lenContent, uint32(contentIntLen))
    content := []byte(m.content)
    sizeTotal:= 21+callbackIdIntLen+targetIntLen+actionIntLen+contentIntLen
    size := make([]byte,4)
    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(size, uint32(sizeTotal))
    b=b[:0]
    b=append(b,size...)
    b=append(b,byte(m.contentType))
    b=append(b,lenCallbackid...)
    b=append(b,lenTarget...)
    b=append(b,lenAction...)
    b=append(b,lenContent...)
    b=append(b,callbackid...)
    b=append(b,target...)
    b=append(b,action...)
    b=append(b,content...)
    res = b
    return b
}

func FromByte(bytes []byte)(*Message){
    size         :=binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(bytes[0:4])
    contentType  :=bytes[4:5][0]
    lenCallbackid:=binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(bytes[5:9])
    lenTarget    :=binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(bytes[9:13])
    lenAction    :=binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(bytes[13:17])
    lenContent   :=binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(bytes[17:21])
    callbackid   := string(bytes[21:21+lenCallbackid])
    target:= string(bytes[21+lenCallbackid:21+lenCallbackid+lenTarget])
    action:= string(bytes[21+lenCallbackid+lenTarget:21+lenCallbackid+lenTarget+lenAction])
    content:=string(bytes[size-lenContent:size])
    return &Message{size,contentType,callbackid,target,action,content}
}
```

`Benchs`:

```
func BenchmarkMessageToByte(b *testing.B) {
    m:=NewMessage(uint8(3),"agsdggsdasagdsdgsgddggds","sometarSFAFFget","somFSAFSAFFSeaction","somfasfsasfafsejsonzhit")
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        m.ToByte()
    }
}


func BenchmarkMessageFromByte(b *testing.B) {
    m:=NewMessage(uint8(1),"sagdsgaasdg","soSASFASFASAFSFASFAGmetarget","adsgdgsagdssgdsgd","agsdsdgsagdsdgasdg").ToByte()
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        FromByte(m)
    }
}


func BenchmarkStringToByte(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        _ = []byte("abcdefghijklmnoqrstuvwxyz")
    }
}

func BenchmarkStringFromByte(b *testing.B) {
    s:=[]byte("abcdefghijklmnoqrstuvwxyz")
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        _ = string(s)
    }
}


func BenchmarkUintToByte(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        i:=make([]byte,4)
        binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(i, uint32(99))
    }
}

func BenchmarkUintFromByte(b *testing.B) {
    i:=make([]byte,4)
    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(i, uint32(99))
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(i)
    }
}
```

**Bench results:**

```
   BenchmarkMessageToByte     10000000               280 ns/op
   BenchmarkMessageFromByte   10000000               293 ns/op
   BenchmarkStringToByte      50000000               55.1 ns/op
   BenchmarkStringFromByte    50000000               49.7 ns/op
   BenchmarkUintToByte        1000000000             2.14 ns/op
   BenchmarkUintFromByte      2000000000             1.71 ns/op
```

Comment: @GrzegorzŻur yes its exactly the total  length of all arrays

Comment: "More efficient" in what way? Performance or code size?

Comment: Performance code size does not matter at least for this struct only which is a message that i serialize into a byte payload, to send over tcp

Comment: Just to clarify for future readers, the idea is to change your `func (m *Message) ToByte() []byte` into `func (m *Message) ToByte(p []byte) []byte` and allow the caller to pass in a buffer which you append to. Callers can then optionally re-use the same buffer (or not). Several functions in the standard library operate like that as well (e.g. [`hash.Hash`](https://golang.org/pkg/hash/#Hash)'s `Sum` method).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provided memory is already allocated, a sequence of x=append(x,a...) is rather efficient in Go.

In your example, the initial allocation (make) probably costs more than the sequence of appends. It depends on the size of the fields. Consider the following benchmark:

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
)

const sizeTotal = 25

var res []byte // To enforce heap allocation

func BenchmarkWithAlloc(b *testing.B) {

    a := []byte("abcde")

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        x := make([]byte, 0, sizeTotal)
        x = append(x, a...)
        x = append(x, a...)
        x = append(x, a...)
        x = append(x, a...)
        x = append(x, a...)
        res = x // Make sure x escapes, and is therefore heap allocated
    }
}

func BenchmarkWithoutAlloc(b *testing.B) {

    a := []byte("abcde")
    x := make([]byte, 0, sizeTotal)

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        x = x[:0]
        x = append(x, a...)
        x = append(x, a...)
        x = append(x, a...)
        x = append(x, a...)
        x = append(x, a...)
        res = x
    }
}
```

On my box, the result is:

```
testing: warning: no tests to run
PASS
BenchmarkWithAlloc      10000000               116 ns/op              32 B/op          1 allocs/op
BenchmarkWithoutAlloc   50000000                24.0 ns/op             0 B/op          0 allocs/op
```

Systematically reallocating the buffer (even a small one) makes this benchmark at least 5 times slower.

So your best hope to optimize this code it to make sure you do not reallocate a buffer for each packet you build. On the contrary, you should keep your buffer, and reuse it for each marshalling operation.

You can reset a slice while keeping its underlying buffer allocated with the following statement:

```
x = x[:0]
```

Comment: thats neat i am faster than protobuf now thanks for the suggestion,  `BenchmarkMessageToByte            10000000               280 ns/op`
`BenchmarkMessageFromByte        10000000               293 ns/op`

Comment: If you are interested in efficient serialization, you may want to have a look at: https://github.com/alecthomas/go_serialization_benchmarks

Answer (score 2):

I looked carefully at that and made the following benchmarks.

```
package append

import "testing"

func BenchmarkAppend(b *testing.B) {
    as := 1000
    a := make([]byte, as)
    s := make([]byte, 0, b.N*as)
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        s = append(s, a...)
    }
}

func BenchmarkCopy(b *testing.B) {
    as := 1000
    a := make([]byte, as)
    s := make([]byte, 0, b.N*as)
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        copy(s[i*as:(i+1)*as], a)
    }
}
```

The results are

```
grzesiek@klapacjusz ~/g/s/t/append> go test -bench . -benchmem
testing: warning: no tests to run
PASS
BenchmarkAppend 10000000           202 ns/op        1000 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkCopy   10000000           201 ns/op        1000 B/op          0 allocs/op
ok      test/append 4.564s
```

If the `totalSize` is big enough then your code makes no memory allocations. It copies only the amount of bytes it needs to copy. It is perfectly fine.