# What is the fastest way to concatenate several []byte together?

Tags: performance, optimization, go, concatenation, slice

Right now I'm using the code below (as in `BenchmarkEncoder()`) and it's fast, but I'm wondering if there is a faster, more efficient way. I benchmark with `GOMAXPROCS=1` and:

```
sudo -E nice -n -20 go test -bench . -benchmem -benchtime 3s
```

.

```
package blackbird

import (
    "testing"
    "encoding/hex"
    "log"
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
)

var (
    d1, d2, d3, d4, outBytes []byte
    toEncode [][]byte
)

func init() {
    var err interface{}
    d1, err = hex.DecodeString("6e5438fd9c3748868147d7a4f6d355dd")
    d2, err = hex.DecodeString("0740e2dfa4b049f2beeb29cc304bdb5f")
    d3, err = hex.DecodeString("ab6743272358467caff7d94c3cc58e8c")
    d4, err = hex.DecodeString("7411c080762a47f49e5183af12d87330e6d0df7dd63a44808db4e250cdea0a36182fce4a309842e49f4202eb90184dd5b621d67db4a04940a29e981a5aea59be")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("hex decoding failed: %v", err)
    }
    toEncode = [][]byte{d1, d2, d3, d4}

}

func Encode(stuff [][]byte) []byte {
    return bytes.Join(stuff, nil)
}

func BenchmarkEncoderDirect(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        bytes.Join(toEncode, nil)
    }
}

func BenchmarkEncoder(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        Encode(toEncode)
    }
}

func BenchmarkJsonEncoder(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        outBytes, _ = json.Marshal(toEncode)

    }
}
```

What is the fastest way to concatenate several `[]byte` together?

Comment: Is the data that has to be decoded predictable in size?

Comment: Length/size of d1, d2, d3 is always 16 bytes (they are UUIDs). d4 can be anywhere between 16 bytes and 1 MiB.

Comment: Try writing to a bytes.Buffer with a capacity initialized to the length needed, which avoids any further copies to grow the underlying slice.

Comment: See also [Concat byte arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29046963/concat-byte-arrays)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`bytes.Join()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Join) is pretty fast, but it does some extra work appending separators between the appendable byte slices. It does so even if the separator is an empty or `nil` slice.

So if you care about the best performance (although it will be a slight improvement), you may do what `bytes.Join()` does without appending (empty) separators: allocate a big-enough byte slice, and copy each slice into the result using the built-in [`copy()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#copy) function.

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/LB9iMbrwAt):

```
func Join(s ...[]byte) []byte {
    n := 0
    for _, v := range s {
        n += len(v)
    }

    b, i := make([]byte, n), 0
    for _, v := range s {
        i += copy(b[i:], v)
    }
    return b
}
```

Using it:

```
concatenated := Join(d1, d2, d3, d4)
```

**Improvements:**

If you know the total size in advance (or you can calculate it faster than looping over the slices), provide it and you can avoid having to loop over the slices in order to count the needed size:

```
func JoinSize(size int, s ...[]byte) []byte {
    b, i := make([]byte, size), 0
    for _, v := range s {
        i += copy(b[i:], v)
    }
    return b
}
```

Using it in your case:

```
concatenated := JoinSize(48 + len(d4), d1, d2, d3, d4)
```

**Notes:**

But if your goal in the end is to write the concatenated byte slice into an [`io.Writer`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer), performance wise it is better not to concatenate them but write each into it separately.

Comment: I've just benchmarked both of your suggestions and they are indeed faster than what I have now. JoinSize() is the fastest function so far. Its speed is 101 ns/op compared to 117 ns/op.

Comment: Think of all the things you could do with that extra 8ns! /s ;)

Comment: @elithrar It's 16 ns! Execute it 1.8 billiard times (`1.8e12`), and now you have an extra holiday from work!

Answer (score 2):

In general, @icza's answer is right. For your specific use-case, however, you can allocate once and decode into that buffer much more efficiently:

[Like this:](http://play.golang.org/p/VjvxdiRUj5)

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/hex"
)

func main() {
    h1 := []byte("6e5438fd9c3748868147d7a4f6d355dd")
    h2 := []byte("0740e2dfa4b049f2beeb29cc304bdb5f")
    h3 := []byte("ab6743272358467caff7d94c3cc58e8c")
    h4 := []byte("7411c080762a47f49e5183af12d87330e6d0df7dd63a44808db4e250cdea0a36182fce4a309842e49f4202eb90184dd5b621d67db4a04940a29e981a5aea59be")

    tg := make([]byte, 16+16+16+(1024*1024)) // allocate enough space for the 3 IDs and a max 1MB of extra data

    hex.Decode(tg[:16], h1)
    hex.Decode(tg[16:32], h2)
    hex.Decode(tg[32:48], h3)
    l, _ := hex.Decode(tg[48:], h4)

    tg = tg[:48+l]
}
```

At the end of that code, `tg` holds the 3 IDs plus the variable-length 4th chunk of data, decoded, contiguously.

Comment: I use hex encoded bytes in my test as a sample of data. I do not actually use hex.DecodeString() in real code, thats why they are not a part of the benchmark functions.

Comment: The idea is good if we may specify the target slice we want the results in (as you did with `hex.Decode()`). But note that even if it is so, this solution might be quite inefficient if  `h4` is small (e.g. just a few bytes) as it allocates a ~1MB slice and will use just like 50 bytes (the result). Also note that even though you reslice it at the end, the whole 1 MB array will be kept in memory as long as the slice will be. If `h4` is big, then this is a good optimization.

Comment: They _were_ asking for the **fastest** method.